# Long delays before executing shell commands

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, performance, zsh

I'm using a MacBook Pro 15-inch (2017), macOS Ventura 13.6.3.  When I try to run a command, any command, in a shell, there will often be a delay before the command starts, usually on the order of minutes.

- This happens *before* any command results display. I believe the commands are not executing at all during this delay.
- I have noticed no pattern as to which commands trigger this delay.
- My prompt, which displays elapsed time for the previous command, does not track this delay.
- I have checked in Activity Monitor and am not CPU- or memory-bound.

While getting details for this post, I noticed that the About This Mac dialog can also be delayed. I have not noticed delays in any other GUI applications.

It seems to have stopped for now, but has anyone else noticed similar issues and found a solution?

ETA: I have tried logging out and restarting; the problem persisted.

ETA (2): Now it's doing it at the end of running commands as well.

Comment: You say it has stopped for now, so did it do it for an extended period prior to it stopping? Also, when you open your Terminal application, does it take a while for the command prompt to actually appear? If so (and I had/have this issue), then you may have a  `~/.profile`  (or similar) that is doing loads of background tasks - these are sometimes added by a third party installer (mine was an Intel AI related package). Maybe check to see if you have a `~/.profile` and then check what is in it. I've never noticed a *per-command delay* though, only upon opening Terminal.

Comment: @Greenonline yes, it was doing it for an extended period, including across restarts (I forgot to mention that). It takes a few seconds for a terminal to start—I know my `~/.zshrc` is overstuffed—but nothing like what I'm seeing now.

Comment: You may have a `preexec` [hook function](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Hook-Functions) that is going haywire. `add-zsh-hook -L` will list the various hook functions; you can try running them directly to see if anything there is causing the delay.

Comment: Does this even happen for builtin command, for instance if you type a  lone `:`? If so, I suspect a preexec hook, as Gairfowl said. If not, I would check whether your PATH contains a directory on the network, which, when accessed, runs into a timeout.

Comment: It's doing it again for `add-zsh-hook -L` and `echo $PATH`, which is making specific diagnosis tricky but makes @Gairfowl's answer look more likely.

Comment: Seems to have stopped after I massively stripped down my `.zshrc`, anyway. Thanks everyone!